# Problema al querer pagar mercado pago en modo sandbox con php

Tags: php, html, formularios, mercadopago

estoy intentando realizar el pago ficticio de mercado pago en modo sandbox con pago facil, al devolverme los codigos de pago, voy al pago facil se lo digo a la cajera y le dice algo asi como "codigo no valido", este el codigo que estoy usando.

```
<?php 
session_start();

require_once ("sdk-php-master/lib/mercadopago.php");

$mp = new MP("inserto aqui mi client_id", "inserto aqui mi client_Secret");

$preference_data = array(
"items" => array(
    array(
        "title" => "Productos Cubiertas Oeste",
        "currency_id" => "ARG",
        "category_id" => "Category",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "unit_price" => (float)$_POST['total']
    )
),
"payer" => array(
        "name" => $_POST['nombre'],
        "surname" => $_POST['apellido'],
        "email" => $_POST['email'],
        "date_created" => "2017-03-15",
        ),
"phone" => array(
        "area_code" => $_POST['cod_area'],
        "number" => $_POST['telefono']
),
"identification" => array(
        "type" => $_POST['tipo_dni'],
        "number" => $_POST['dni']
),
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <a href="<?php echo $preference["response"]["sandbox_init_point"]; ?>"    name="MP-Checkout" class="orange-ar-m-sq-arall">Pay</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//resources.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js"></script>
```

Los datos del array multi dimensional los traigo desde un formulario de otra pagina con el metodo POST como pueden ver. No creo que haga falta insertarles aqui el codigo html del formulario.

Todo anda bien  mi problema sencillamente es al momento del pago.

Saludos !!